# Using LED light bulbs in a dimmer

Tags: light-fixture, led, bulb, halogen

I have this light fixture: 
[image: fixture 1] 
[image: fixture 2]

that used halogen light bulbs (philips ecovantage, 500 lumens, 120v, PAR FLOOD25) - ll failed during the same week but one:
[image: old glob]

I wanted to replace them with those LED light bulbs:
http://www.amazon.ca/Globe-Electric-30822-Directional-Equivalent/dp/B00KFWME2A

When I put them in the fixture, they won't do anything at all even if the dimmer is maxed. I tried them in another socket in the apartment, and the globes do work. I left the halogen bulb in, so now I have 4 unlit LED light bulbs and 1 lit halogen light bulb. Why is that? They were pretty expensive :(

Thanks

Comment: Many LED bulbs are not dimmable. Even though your dimmer is on "max", it may not be at "100%" and that could be freaking out the power supplies in the LED bulbs. Do the bulbs or their cartons say "not for use with dimmers" or "dimmable"?

Comment: @DoktorJ Sorry I moved and gave the bulbs to someone, so I don't know. I will keep that in mind next time :)

Answer (score 2):

Many dimmers need a minimum wattage load to function. Four of the LEDs is 29.2W and is probably too low for the dimmer. The single remaining halogen alone is 39W (I assume it worked with the dimmer alone) so it's close. Try replacing the dimmer with one designed for LEDs.

Comment: Did I read correctly? you said out of the 5 sockets you have 4xLED and one Halogen?, In my mind that sometimes does work.  But yes, must be the dimmer.

Comment: ok! Thanks! I googled a bit before asking, and that's what I read - that dimmers might need a minimum wattage. What I didn't get is why the halogen bulb would light up when the LED bulbs are in, but the LED bulbs wouldn't!